# null value passed from DataGridViewRow despite checks

Tags: c#-4.0

The goal of this piece of code is to get each DataGridViewRow  THAT CONTAINS DATA as a separate element in the List. The problem is that empty rows are being recorded as well.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    List<int> rowtemp = new List<int>();
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        if (cell.Value!=null && cell.Value.ToString().Length > 0)//empty cells are passing this check. Why?
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(cell.Value.ToString(), out v) == true)
                rowtemp.Add(v);
            else
                ErrorLog("Value must be single number in each cell. It is: " + cell.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
    xmlParse(rowtemp);
}
```

Comment: Please put a bit more effort into formatting code in your questions - your method body was indented way more than it needed to be, making it harder to read the question. Next, please give more detail than "this piece of code errors out" - what *exactly* happens? If an exception is thrown, give the full stack trace, indicating the line in your code.

Comment: (Also consider using whitespace more effectively - the expression `cell.Value!=null&&cell.Value.ToString().Length>0` is *much* harder to read than `cell.Value != null && cell.Value.ToString().Length > 0`...)

Comment: Code updated to reflect suggestions

Comment: You still haven't indicated which line is failing...

Comment: Try String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.Value.ToString()) instead of checking the length.